# JavaScript - Generate random pixels on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, web

I want to create a random generated image (random colors), like [this one](https://image.ibb.co/buJkTb/1.png). But, I want to do it in javascript, but for some reason I am getting black screen.

Here is my code:

```
var g=document . createElement( 'canvas').getContext('2d');
g.canvas.width=g.canvas.height = 800;
g.imgd = g.getImageData(0, 0, 800, 800);
g.data = g.imgd.data;

g.data.forEach((_, index) => (index & 3) < 3 && (g.data[index] = Math.random()));
g.putImageData(g.imgd, 0, 0);

document.body.appendChild(g.canvas);;;
```

And i am getting black screen, and on some websites it is white screen. So what is what not working in my script? My english is not very good, but can someone explain what is wrong, my code dont'esnt working.

I also tried different dimensions of canvas and I dont see any errors so what is wrong?

Comment: Are there actually spaces between document and createElement?

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Math.random()` which generates floats from 0 to 1 without including 1. Since you're applying zeroes to the color components (the data from `getImageData().data`), you get the color black (`rgb(0, 0, 0)`).

Here's a more readable solution:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = canvas.height = 800;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

for (var i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
  imgData.data[i] = randomInt(0, 255); // red
  imgData.data[i+1] = randomInt(0, 255); // green
  imgData.data[i+2] = randomInt(0, 255); // blue
  imgData.data[i+3] = 255; // alpha
}

ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` returns a floating point number, not within the full range of 0-255. You can alternatively use `.fillStyle()` and set the color to a random hex color.

```js
function pixels(width = 100, height = 100, size = 1, canvas) {

  var canvas = canvas || document.createElement("canvas");
  
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  var total = [];
  
  canvas.width = width;
  
  canvas.height = height;

  function random() {
    return "XXXXXX".replace(/X/g, function() {
      var seed = "a0b1c2d3e4f56789";
      return seed.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * seed.length))
    })
  };
  
  for (var x = 0; x <= width; x += size) {
    total.push(x)
  };

  total.forEach(function(value, index) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= height; i++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = "#" + random();
      ctx.fillRect(value, total[i], size, size);
    }
  });
  
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  
  return ctx;
  
};

var c = pixels(window.innerWidth - 20, window.innerHeight - 20);
```